# How to do metered subscriptions in Laravel Cashier?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I want to do metered subscriptions using Stripe + Laravel Cashier. I want to bill the customer at the end of the period based on my criteria. Is there a way in Cashier to do this? I couldn't find a way.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/555

Answer (score 2):

in your controller when subscribe a user: call newsubscription with quantity NULL

$this->newSubscription('metered product') ->quantity(null) ->create();

and then manually send request to stripe for adding usage and increment related item quantity in cashier table at the same time. [Usage Record Api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create)